# jgit blame has null commit shas for some lines of a file

Tags: java, windows, git, jgit, core.autocrlf

Sometimes when I do the following:

```
BlameCommand blamer = new BlameCommand(repo);
ObjectId commitID = repo.resolve("head");
blamer.setStartCommit("head");
blamer.setFilePath(fileName);
BlameResult blame = blamer.call();
RevCommit commit = blame.getSourceCommit(0); //set to first line but can be random line of file
```

The commit obtained from the last line in the sample code is `null`; it is not always `null`, just on some lines of some files. I suspected it has to do with CR/LF issues as I am running this code on a windows machine so I tried changing both my global and repository config `core.autocrlf` values. I tried both true and false for core.autocrlf but I still have the same problem.

Currently using:
jgit-3.1.0.201310021548

Comment: Sounds like a bug in JGit. Could you try to reproduce this using a repository that is publicly accessible (e.g. the JGit repository itself) and then [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I added a snippet at the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBlame.java) that uses the BlameCommand, it works fine there, in your sample code the setStartCommit() is wrong, it should be the commitID.

The following works for me:

```
    BlameCommand blamer = new BlameCommand(repository);
    ObjectId commitID = repository.resolve("HEAD");
    blamer.setStartCommit(commitID);
    blamer.setFilePath("README.md");
    BlameResult blame = blamer.call();
```

Comment: I had removed unneeded parts of the sample code and accidentally introduced the typo. Typo is now fixed. But I still have this issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer and edited the question to show the incorrect code as it was in the original question. It is probably not useful to "fix" the code in the question as it makes the question useless and confusing....